# Angular-messages appears & vanishes whenever page is Reloaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two **ng-messages** associated with one **Text field** but I want one **Message** as a default -
  *This field is Mandatory!*
 which loads with the page get refreshed/opened 
but the second one i.e *Username contains atleast 3 characters* should only shown when atleast one text entered into the **textbox**.

Whenever the page is loaded the second message which didnt required is shown and then vanishes when the page is loaded completely,How can I remove this and make the page more prominent.

Here's my code what I am trying is

```
 <div class="errormsg" ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error">
 <div ng-message="required">This field is Mandatory!</div>
 <div ng-message="minlength">Username contains atleast 3 characters</div>
 </div>
```

Suggest me a way to achieve this in angular.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$pristine` alongwith `$invalid`. See below example. I am using help-block instead of ng-message. You can add additional validations like min length, max length etc as desired.

```
<form name="contactUsForm" ng-submit="sendContactUsMessage();" novalidate>

                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : contactUsForm.name.$invalid && !contactUsForm.name.$pristine }">
                    <label for="name">Name<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk mandatory" aria-hidden="true" /></label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="When were you born?" ng-model="message.name" ng-required="true">
                    <p ng-show="contactUsForm.name.$invalid && !contactUsForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Name is required.</p>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `$dirty` instead of `!$pristine`.

Comment: Yes, but `$dirty` would not be useful in case I write something in input box and erase it completely using backspace.

Comment: No, they are precise opposites. If you modify a form, then delete your modifications, it will still be `$dirty`. See the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Yes. Sorry, my bad, they are exactly opposite in nature.